# Sorting text rows by integer value

Tags: java, sorting, text, numbers

i need a little help with sorting text rows.

```
Kazimira Danutė PRUNSKIENĖ : 3,86%
Dalia GRYBAUSKAITĖ : 68,21%
Valdemar TOMAŠEVSKI : 4,68%
Algirdas BUTKEVIČIUS : 11,68%
Valentinas MAZURONIS : 6,08%
Česlovas JEZERSKAS : 0,66%
Loreta GRAUŽINIENĖ : 3,57%
```

I need to sort this text document by numbers.

```
Dalia GRYBAUSKAITĖ : 68,21%
Algirdas BUTKEVIČIUS : 11,68%
Valentinas MAZURONIS : 6,08%
Valdemar TOMAŠEVSKI : 4,68%
Kazimira Danutė PRUNSKIENĖ : 3,86%
Loreta GRAUŽINIENĖ : 3,57%
Česlovas JEZERSKAS : 0,66%
```

What is best way to do this?

```
           Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(desktopPath + "/RINKIMAI/INFO.txt"), "UTF-8");
           @SuppressWarnings("resource")
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

          java.util.List<Float> allMatches = new ArrayList<Float>();
           String word = null;
           while((word =br.readLine()) != null){
               Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+");
               Matcher m = p.matcher(word); 
               while (m.find()) {
                   allMatches.add(Float.parseFloat(m.group()));   
               }
               Arrays.sort(allMatches);
           }
```

I'm unable to put all parsed information into array, because it's float type, can't find solution.. And still is it possible after sorting all info in descending to bring back full rows with all information in descending?

Comment: Did you try **anything**?

Comment: I'm trying. sorry for lazy post.

Answer (score 2):

Write a `Comparator` that compares two `String` values by splitting them on `":"` and parsing a `float` out of the second section.  Then use either `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`, passing in that `Comparator`.

Comment: Thanks, you are giving clues there to start.

Comment: Clues?  I thought I told you exactly how to do it!